# ufw closed port in auth.log

Tags: server, security, ufw

UFW blocks all incoming ports, except a few that I opened.

In auth.log I see a lot of attempts to get in through closed ports.
Like:

```
Connection closed by 52.167.224.94 port 40030 [preauth]
```

This port should be closed by UFW.
Why does it appear in auth.log?
Is this a security risk?
Is there a good web page where I can read more about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

40030 is the client side port, or source port. If I run `ssh foobar@example.com`, and interrupt the login before sending a password, the following will turn up in the logs:

```
Apr  5 16:09:15 example.com sshd[8164]: Connection closed by 192.168.0.1 port 54250 [preauth]
```

From the beginning, there's the timestamp, the machines name (example.com), which daemon[pid of daemon]: what happened by which client on which port [in which stage]

So this was a connection from 52.167.224.94, remote port 40030, probably to sshd on your machine, that were closed by the remote end during pre-authentication.

The port range the connection comes from is called [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), and vary a bit by OS, but is generally >25000.

When you quote log lines, include the whole line. If there's any private info, redact it and indicate that it's redacted.